# Add a extra field to ActiveModel Serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, active-model-serializers

Lets say I am having a Model called Vendor(id, name, lat, lon, created_at).
And i have a query in which i find distance of vendors from the current latitude and longitude.

Query is -

```
query = "*, ST_Distance(ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(#{lat}, #{lon}), 4326)::geography,ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(lat, lon), 4326)::geography) as distance"

Vendor.select(query)
```

I have serializer class as -

```
class VendorSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :id,
               :lat,
               :lon,
               :name,
               :created_at

    def attributes
        hash = super
        # I tried to override attributes and added distance but it doesn't add
        hash[:distance] = object.distance if object.distance.present?
        hash
    end
end
```

I want to have a serialised object as {id, lat, lon, name, created_at,  distance}. 
So the model attributes get attached but how can i add the extra field/attribute i.e, "distance" to the serialised hash?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

AMS has built-in support for this. No need for dirty hacks.

```
class VendorSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :lat, :lon, :name, :created_at,
             :distance, :foobar


  def include_distance?
    object.distance.present?
  end

  def foobar
    'custom value'
  end

  def include_foobar?
    # ...
  end
end
```

For every attribute, AMS will try find and call method `include_ATTR?`. If the method exists and returns falsey value, the attribute is not included in the output.

Comment: This is not giving me "distance " in json.

Comment: @palash-kulkarni: can't reproduce. Works for me.

Comment: I tried this too. But didnt work. I think the extra attribute which we want and have in the select query as "distance" and which is not a part of Vendor model. So it is not getting added

Comment: @palash-kulkarni: ah, that may be. In this case, indeed, serializing vendor seems useless. You could just bypass all the things (creating vendors and serializing them) and output your resultset directly.

Comment: How it can be useless if somebody wants all the other attributes along with the extra field?

Comment: @palash-kulkarni: because someone wants that extra field and it's not available on a Vendor.

Answer (score -1):

You can do like following

```
class VendorSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :id,
               :lat,
               :lon,
               :name,
               :created_at,
               :some_extra_attribute

    def some_extra_attribute
      object.some_extra_attribute # Or any other calculation inside this method
    end


end
```

Comment: Downvoting, bcoz not explained how to use this method `some_extra_attribute`.

Comment: What Rails API has to do with this? It is not mentioned anywhere in you answer how can i call this `some_extra_attribute` method from this serialize or how do I include the result of this `some_extra_attribute` method to my response. Does it gets automatically append to the serialized json? Because that was not happening.

Comment: It is actually mentioned. If you have a look at line #2, `attributes :id, :lan, :etc` this is how rails knows which attributes to serialize into response. You dont need to explicitly call any methods, rails does it for you

As for rails api - you need to know interface of railse's classes in order to use them, so I encourage you to go and read what and how serializer in rails works to stop making wrong decisions based on your own limited knowledge

Answer (score -1):

Here are guides to active model serializer:
[Active Model Serializer Guide](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/0-10-stable/docs/README.md)

Resolution to your problem is defining here:
[Active Model Serializer Guide - Serializer](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/0-10-stable/docs/general/serializers.md)

Comment: Link-only answers are not very useful. Include the _relevant_ part of the linked article in the answer itself.